# In Simpy, how do I sync two processes to start a third process?

Tags: python, simulation, yield, simpy, event-simulation

I am trying to simulate a manufacturing process with multiple machines. Machine1 has a volumetric capacity of 1 liter. Machine2 has a volumetric capacity of 2 liters. We want to produce 2 liters of chemical X. So we put in 1L of raw material in Machine1. Once done, move that 1L to Machine2. Meanwhile, run another round on Machine1 with a second batch of 1L. Then add this to the already half filled Machine2. Then start Machine2 to finally produce two liters. If Machine1 takes 3 hours and Machine2 takes 12 hours, this process will take 3 + 3 + 12 = 18 hours.

Now my approach is as follows. I create Machine1 as a resource with capacity 1 and Machine2 as a resource with capacity 2. I wish to start Machine2 after both batches have passed through Machine1. My attempted code is below:

```
import simpy
from collections import namedtuple

Chemical = namedtuple("Chemical", "name")

X_batch1 = Chemical("X_batch1")
X_batch2 = Chemical("X_batch2")


def do_process_1(env, machine1, Chemical):
    print(f"Chemical {Chemical.name} requested Machine1 at {env.now}")
    with machine1.request() as req:
        yield req
        print(f"Chemical {Chemical.name} got into Machine1 at {env.now}")
        yield env.timeout(3)
        print(f"Chemical {Chemical.name} got out of Machine1 at {env.now}")
        # yield env.timeout(2)


def do_process_2(env, machine1, machine2, Chemicals):

    # <some condition to check if process 1 is done for both Chemicals>

    # make each batch for machine2, one after the other
    print(f"{Chemicals[0]} asks for Machine2 at {env.now}.")
    print(f"{Chemicals[1]} asks for Machine2 at {env.now}.")
    with machine2.request() as req1, machine2.request() as req2:
        yield req1 & req2
        print(f"{Chemicals[0]} gets machine2 at {env.now}.")
        print(f"{Chemicals[1]} gets Machine2 at {env.now}.")
        yield env.timeout(12)
    print(f"{Chemicals[0]} got out of machine2 at {env.now}.")
    print(f"{Chemicals[1]} got out of machine2 at {env.now}.")


env = simpy.Environment()
machine1 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)
machine2 = simpy.Resource(env, 2)

env.process(do_process_1(env, machine1, X_batch1))
env.process(do_process_1(env, machine1, X_batch2))
env.process(do_process_2(env, machine2, machine1, (X_batch1, X_batch2)))
env.run(until=60)
```

I have two roadblocks above:

1. The Machine2 should be requested only after both machines are done with machine 1. I am not sure how to add this condition, and where to add it.
2. Machine2 must be requested twice (by different batches), and should proceed to begin work after that. It should not begin work when there is only one request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question with the code below. In short, I save the processes of the first machine in a variable and pass that variable to the second machine. And then I use a yield with that process in the second machine's process.

```
import simpy
from collections import namedtuple

Chemical = namedtuple("Chemical", "name")

X_batch1 = Chemical("X_batch1")
X_batch2 = Chemical("X_batch2")


def do_process_1(env, machine1, Chemical):
    print(f"Chemical {Chemical.name} requested Machine1 at {env.now}")
    with machine1.request() as req:
        yield req
        print(f"Chemical {Chemical.name} got into Machine1 at {env.now}")
        yield env.timeout(3)
        print(f"Chemical {Chemical.name} got out of Machine1 at {env.now}")
        # yield env.timeout(2)


def do_process_2(env, machine2, Chemicals, procs):

    yield env.all_of(procs)

    # make each batch for machine2, one after the other
    print(f"{Chemicals[0]} asks for Machine2 at {env.now}.")
    with machine2.request() as req1, machine2.request() as req2:
        yield req1 & req2
        print(f"{Chemicals[0]} gets machine2 at {env.now}.")
        yield env.timeout(12)
    print(f"{Chemicals[0]} got out of machine2 at {env.now}.")


env = simpy.Environment()
machine1 = simpy.Resource(env, 1)
machine2 = simpy.Resource(env, 2)

proc1 = env.process(do_process_1(env, machine1, X_batch1))
proc2 = env.process(do_process_1(env, machine1, X_batch2))
env.process(do_process_2(env, machine2, (X_batch1), (proc1, proc2)))
env.process(do_process_2(env, machine2, (X_batch2), (proc1, proc2)))
env.run(until=60)
```